# CORS Error when Accessing ASP.NET Core 6 Web API Remotely via Ngrok

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, ngrok

I've developed a Web API using ASP.NET Core 6 and I want to test it remotely before deploying it. To achieve this, I'm using Ngrok to expose my local server to a public URL.

The Ngrok-generated URL works fine and is accessible to everyone. However, when I try to fetch data from the API using this URL, I encounter a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error.

It's important to note that I've already configured CORS in my Program.cs file and there are no issues when I fetch data from the API on the same device.

[image]

[image]

What I've done:

```
- I've configured CORS in the Program.cs file using AddCors and UseCors methods.
- I'm able to access the API endpoints locally without any CORS issues.
- I've generated a Ngrok URL that points to my local server and verified that it's working.
- I've ensured that my API controllers have the \[ApiController\] attribute.
- I've added the appropriate CORS policies to allow all origins during testing.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, your configurations are almost true but ensure that the order of your middleware configuration is correct. For example, make sure that CORS middleware is placed before any authentication middleware like `app.UseAuthentication()`.